# Capture strings between Q- and X- through regexp_substr

Tags: regex, oracle

I want to capture strings between two specific strings in oracle using REGEXP_SUBSTR, it works in regex101 but when I use it in oracle it doesn’t work. Any one can help?

`Pattern: ^Q-.*[\S\s]*?^X-.*`

```
Data:
A-bbbbbb;cccccc;ggggggg
Addrffjfjfjffj
Fjfjfjf
B-rjfjfjffjfj;fjfjffj;tkgkfck
Q-fjfjfjfj;fkfkffkj;gkfkfk
Djfjfjjfjffjfjfj
Fjfjfjfjf
X-fjfjfjf;fjfnfjf;af
Z-fjfjfjfjfjfjfj;gkgjfjcnf;gkgjgk
```

https://regex101.com/r/Df9RU6/1

```
Result/Captured: 
Q-fjfjfjfj;fkfkffkj;gkfkfk
Djfjfjjfjffjfjfj
Fjfjfjfjf
X-fjfjfjf;fjfnfjf;af
```

Comment: Please show how you used it with REGEXP_SUBSTR().

Comment: REGEXP_SUBSTR(STRINGS,’ ^Q-.*[\S\s]*?^X-.*’,1,1,’m’)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It doesn’t work. I need to specify caret since Q- and X- are always in the beginning and the multi line flag should be there (‘m’).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `'[^\n]'` matches any character that is not either \ or `n` as Oracle does not support PERL-like expressions inside character lists. You would want to use `'[^' || CHR(10) || ']'`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*Do not use regex101 to test Oracle regular expressions; it does not use the same regular expression syntax so you cannot be sure that the query works.*

Oracle does not support PERL-like expressions inside character lists such as `[\s\S]`. If you want to use something similar then use POSIX character classes:

```
([[:space:]]|[^[:space:]])
```

However, what you appear to want is:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         value,
         '(^|' || CHR(10) || ')(Q-(' || CHR(10) || '|.)*?' || CHR(10) || 'X-.*)',
         1,
         1,
         NULL,
         2
       ) AS match
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT 'A-bbbbbb;cccccc;ggggggg
Addrffjfjfjffj
Fjfjfjf
B-rjfjfjffjfj;fjfjffj;tkgkfck
Q-fjfjfjfj;fkfkffkj;gkfkfk
Djfjfjjfjffjfjfj
Fjfjfjfjf
X-fjfjfjf;fjfnfjf;af
Z-fjfjfjfjfjfjfj;gkgjfjcnf;gkgjgk' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| MATCH |
| --- |
| Q-fjfjfjfj;fkfkffkj;gkfkfk Djfjfjjfjffjfjfj Fjfjfjfjf X-fjfjfjf;fjfnfjf;af |

---

However, regular expressions are slow. Even though it is more to type, using simple string functions may be much more performant:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(
         value,
         spos + 1,
         CASE
         WHEN INSTR(value, CHR(10), epos + 1) > 0
         THEN INSTR(value, CHR(10), epos + 1)
         ELSE LENGTH(value) + 1
         END - spos - 1
       ) AS match
FROM   (
  SELECT CHR(10) || value AS value,
         INSTR(CHR(10) || value, CHR(10) || 'Q-') AS spos,
         INSTR(
           CHR(10) || value,
           CHR(10) || 'X-',
           INSTR(CHR(10) || value, CHR(10) || 'Q-')
         ) AS epos
  FROM   table_name
)
WHERE  epos > 0;
```

Also has the same output.

---

If you want to get multiple results for each row then use a recursive query:

```sql
WITH rsqfc (id, value, occurrence, max_occurrences) AS (
  SELECT id,
         value,
         1, 
         REGEXP_COUNT(
           value,
           '(^|' || CHR(10) || ')(Q-(' || CHR(10) || '|.)*?' || CHR(10) || 'X-.*)'
         )
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT id, value, occurrence + 1, max_occurrences
  FROM   rsqfc
  WHERE  occurrence < max_occurrences
)
SELECT id,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         value,
         '(^|' || CHR(10) || ')(Q-(' || CHR(10) || '|.)*?' || CHR(10) || 'X-.*)',
         1,
         occurrence,
         NULL,
         2
       ) AS match
FROM   rsqfc;
```

or, using simple (faster) string functions:

```sql
WITH rsqfc (id, value, qpos, xpos) AS (
  SELECT id,
         CHR(10) || value,
         INSTR(CHR(10) || value, CHR(10) || 'Q-'),
         CASE INSTR(CHR(10) || value, CHR(10) || 'Q-')
         WHEN 0
         THEN 0
         ELSE INSTR(
                CHR(10) || value,
                CHR(10) || 'X-',
                INSTR(CHR(10) || value, CHR(10) || 'Q-')
              )
         END
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         value,
         INSTR(value, CHR(10) || 'Q-', xpos + 1),
         CASE INSTR(value, CHR(10) || 'Q-', xpos + 1)
         WHEN 0
         THEN 0
         ELSE INSTR(
                value,
                CHR(10) || 'X-',
                INSTR(CHR(10) || value, CHR(10) || 'Q-', xpos + 1)
              )
         END
  FROM   rsqfc
  WHERE  xpos > 0
)
SELECT id,
       SUBSTR(
         value,
         qpos + 1,
         CASE
         WHEN INSTR(value, CHR(10), xpos + 1) > 0
         THEN INSTR(value, CHR(10), xpos + 1)
         ELSE LENGTH(value) + 1
         END - qpos - 1
       ) AS match
FROM   rsqfc
WHERE  xpos > 0;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, value) AS
SELECT 1, 'A-bbbbbb;cccccc;ggggggg
Addrffjfjfjffj
Fjfjfjf
B-rjfjfjffjfj;fjfjffj;tkgkfck
Q-fjfjfjfj;fkfkffkj;gkfkfk
Djfjfjjfjffjfjfj
Fjfjfjfjf
X-fjfjfjf;fjfnfjf;af
Z-fjfjfjfjfjfjfj;gkgjfjcnf;gkgjgk' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'A-bbbbbb;cccccc;ggggggg
Addrffjfjfjffj
Fjfjfjf
B-rjfjfjffjfj;fjfjffj;tkgkfck
Q-fjfjfjfj;fkfkffkj;gkfkfk
X-jfjfjjfjffjfjfj
Q-jfjfjfjf
X-fjfjfjf;fjfnfjf;af' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

| ID | MATCH |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Q-fjfjfjfj;fkfkffkj;gkfkfk Djfjfjjfjffjfjfj Fjfjfjfjf X-fjfjfjf;fjfnfjf;af |
| 2 | Q-fjfjfjfj;fkfkffkj;gkfkfk X-jfjfjjfjffjfjfj |
| 2 | Q-jfjfjfjf X-fjfjfjf;fjfnfjf;af |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mFCpLlWD)

Comment: @JuanDelaCruz This appears to output your expected output and also matches the regex101 output linked from the question. Please explain which part of the match is missing.

Comment: The first option is better, but it captures all the occurrences if there are multiple occurrences. What I want is to capture one by one first occurrence one row and second occurrence another row and so on and so forth using union all.